# How can I have an application associate with a file type?

Tags: windows, user-interface, registry

I want to replicate built-in tools on most operating systems such as an image viewer, but I want it to be a nice integrated usage.

1. How can a program be "executed on" a clicked image file?
2. How can the step up required for this file to application association be made easy for a user?
3. How does the program know how to handle the image after it is clicked?

I understand that the file association is stored in registry and that the image file data is passed into the program, but I don't know where to begin to code something like this. The resources I've come across seem to be outdated.

Comment: [How to Register a File Type for a New Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-register-a-file-type-for-a-new-application), see also the full chapter [File Types and File Associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-intro). And also _"... How can the step up required for this file to application association be made easy for a user..."_ use an installer builder to install and register your application.

Comment: User friendliness tip : Be sure to ask the user before changing file associations. Your program might not be the one they want as default app.